# How to create segmentation map for image in python

Tags: python, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have an image of a room and pixel coordinates from which I can generate lines. These lines separate the room into wall, floor and ceiling segments. I would like to create a segmentation map for this layout like in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DNRc.png). How can I do this in python?

[image: Image segmention into walls and floot.]

Comment: use `Opencv` https://opencv.org/

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Thank you for your response. Any pointers for what function I should look into?

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html

Comment: Thank you so much, cv2.fillPoly is the fitting tool for my task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate comment for visibility. Credit to @ZarakiKenpachi. I used cv2.fillPoly from open cv to generate polygons for each segment and combine them into one numpy array.